# Pasting from a closed book to an open book

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I'm trying to post from a close book to an open book with VBA.
The code opens and selects the items but will not paste in the open workbook.

```
Sub GetDataClosedBook3()
Dim sourceworkbook As Workbook
'location of the file and data to copy
Dim currentworkbook As Workbook
Set currentworkbook = ThisWorkbook
Set sourceworkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\June.xlsx")
sourceworkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:C11").Copy
currentworkbook.Activate
currentworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
currentworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
sourceworkbook.Close
Set sourceworkbook = Nothing
Set currentworkbook = Nothing
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

I made some updates and still not working. I don't believe it's copying the data. When I open the sheet the data is selected, not copied.

```
Sub GetDataClosedBook4()
    Dim SourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim PasteRange  As Range
    Dim FileName    As String
    FileName = "C:\Users \June.xlsx"
    If Dir(FileName, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox FileName & Chr(10) & "File Not Found", 48, "Not Found"
    Else
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set PasteRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, 1)
        Set SourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(FileName, False, True)
        SourceWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A12").Copy PasteRange
        SourceWorkbook.Close False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: When stepping through the code, does the code copy the range?

Comment: I updated this with this and step thru. For some reason , I don't believe its copying the fields.

Comment: Your updated code works, just remove the space after "Users"

Answer (score 0):

### Copy From Closed Workbook

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub getDataPasteSpecial() ' Copy with multiple options.
    
    Const FilePath As String = "C:\Users\June.xlsx"
    
    If Dir(FilePath) = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "'" & FilePath & "' not found.", vbExclamation, "Not Found"
    Else
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        With Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
            .Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:C11").Copy
            With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, 1)
                .PasteSpecial ' many options.
                ' e.g. you can paste the column widths only using:
                '.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
                With .Worksheet
                    .Activate
                    .Range("A1").Select
                    .Parent.Save
                End With
            End With
            .Close SaveChanges:=False
        End With
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If

End Sub

Sub getDataCopy() ' Copy values, formats and formulas
    
    Const FilePath As String = "C:\Users\June.xlsx"
    
    If Dir(FilePath) = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "'" & FilePath & "' not found.", vbExclamation, "Not Found"
    Else
        Dim dst As Range
        Set dst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, 1)
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        With Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
            .Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:C11").Copy dst
            .Close SaveChanges:=False
        End With
        With dst.Worksheet
            ' Optional, because the selection hasn't changed.
            '.Activate
            '.Range("A1").Select
            .Parent.Save
        End With
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub

Sub getDataAssign() ' Copy only values (most efficient).
    
    Const FilePath As String = "C:\Users\June.xlsx"
    
    If Dir(FilePath) = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "'" & FilePath & "' not found.", vbExclamation, "Not Found"
    Else
        Dim dst As Range
        Set dst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, 1)
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        With Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
            With .Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:C11")
                dst.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
            End With
            .Close SaveChanges:=False
        End With
        With dst.Worksheet
            ' Optional, because the selection hasn't changed.
            '.Activate
            '.Range("A1").Select
            .Parent.Save
        End With
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub

Sub getDataSilentAssign() ' Silently (opening another Excel) copy only values.
    
    Const FilePath As String = "C:\Users\June.xlsx"
    
    If Dir(FilePath) = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "'" & FilePath & "' not found.", vbExclamation, "Not Found"
    Else
        With New Excel.Application
            .Visible = False
            With .Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
                Dim Data As Variant
                Data = .Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:C11").Value
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With
            .Quit
        End With
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, 1)
            .Resize(UBound(Data, 1), UBound(Data, 2)) = Data
            .Worksheet.Parent.Save
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```